# When having 10 series hightcharts scatter is freezing

Tags: highcharts

I am viewing 10 series of data in my scatter graph.

On less than 10 series I have no problem, however, once I reach 10 series of data the scatter graph shows the scatter but all with circles that cant be clicked instead of their original shapes.

Example in the image below all shapes showing as circles

[image]

Comment: Can you share a working example for that?

Comment: Hi @Hassan Abdul Ghaffar, Do you use `boost` module? In this example: http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/mtzj1v4x/ everything works correctly.

Comment: Yes, using boost but even when disabled it is not working

Comment: @Hassan Abdul Ghaffar - Please reproduce that issue in some online code editor. You can edit the example that I provided.

Comment: @ppotaczek Disabling Boost completely fixed my problem, thanks!